# SQL Query to Find tuples with maximum number of identical values

Tags: sql

Any ideas how to implement the query:

You are given a relation with N columns of the same type. Write an SQL2 query that returns the
tuples having the maximum number of identical values. The query should have size polynomial in
N.

Comment: This sounds like homework, and usually people don't like "plz gimme teh codez" type of questions. Posting a sample table and what you got so far with your tries might help, too.

Comment: What RDBMS does the class you attend deals with?

Comment: @Alex - please don't mark questions as homework just because _you_ think they are. This should be done by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

yo u better hope prof. chomicki doesn't see this considering you used for real name
and at @Alex you were right http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~chomicki/462/p1.pdf